# How can i get Json Data if its having in particular Name

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

Here im having data Like

```
""{\"resultStatus\":\"success\",\"message\":\"AUTH-040010: Successfully logout user\",\"language\":\"en\",\"region\":\"us\",\"securityToken\":\"C29F32A5-CF46-4CE8-B1DF-4FBC207ABA19|13|1550120060454\",\"userName\":\"John\",\"organisationId\":1,\"isSearch\":false,\"productId\":1,\"productKey\":\"fAyhhy455Hh4d52c\",\"menuKey\":\"LOG\",\"pageDto\":{\"selectedPage\":1,\"totalCount\":0,\"recodsPerPage\":25},\"menuMasterDtoList\":{},\"validated\":true}Redirectdata=https://192.168.10.19:8089/iauth/access/login?productId=1&productKey=f8cc80d…a24d52c&redirectUrl=http://172.16.1.135:458/Enquiry/openenquiries&Message= Success&MessageType=1""
```

in this Url How can  i get  **Redirectdata**  Url

```
JSON.stringify(d.data)  By using this i convert that string in Json
```

But

```
JSON.stringify(d.data.Redirectdata)
```

This is Giving me undefind
Please help me how can i get Redirectdata Url

Comment: Looks like your `data` is not valid anymore. Please post minimum example.

Comment: @SudhirOjha i did not understand??

Comment: Can you post your actual format of data.

Comment: @SudhirOjha please go to my data..I had Just Updated

Answer (score 3):

It because Redirectdata is not a JSON key its outside of JSON object

Comment: do uhave any idea How can i get

Comment: can you post your code to get this values from json ?